# Adding an array object to Users collection in Meteor.js

Tags: meteor

I'm very new to *Meteor.js* and I'm finding the documentation a bit hard to understand.

I'm starting with a very simple app where Users will simply be allowed to add existing *Games* to their profile by clicking a button. The *Games* are stored in another Meteor Collection.

In rails I would just create a `has_and_belongs_to_many` relationship but that isn't how Meteor works. I thought the best way would be to add an empty array when the user's account is created - then, when they click the "add game" button it would pass the game's title into the users array.

I have this in my */server/users.js* file:

```js
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    user.games = [];
    return user;
});

Meteor.methods({
    addGame: function(title) {
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $addToSet: { games: title}});
    }
});
```

And I'm making a call to the `addGame` method in my */client/views/games/games_list.js* file as such:

```js
Template.gamesList.events({
    'click .add-to-chest-btn': function(e){
        var title = $(e.target).attr('name');
        e.preventDefault();
        Meteor.call('addGame', title, function(title){ console.log(title)});
    }
});
```

Am I on the right track or is there a better way to do this?

Comment: I think that should be an acceptable way to do it.

Now you can try, client side:

    Meteor.call("addGame",gameId, function(err,result){
       console.log(result)
    });       Have you tried this yet?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You're on the right track, but do declare an array instead of an object:

```
Accounts.onCreateUser(function(options, user){
    user.games = [];
    return user;
});
```

Push the value directly instead of an object, and use `$addToSet` to avoid duplicates in case you push the same `gameId` multiple times:

```
Meteor.methods({
    addGame: function(gameId) {
        Meteor.users.update(Meteor.userId(), { $addToSet: { games: gameId }});
    }
});
```

Comment: I think this is getting me pretty close - I've updated the OP with my updated code but it still isn't working.

Comment: Can you give a bit more info on why it is not working? E.g., error message, log

Comment: the console just says "undefined"

Comment: could it have something to do with the subscriptions / publications for users? I removed the Autopublish package

Comment: I guess you refer to DrM's call above: your `addGame` method does not return anything. Add `return Meteor.user();` at the end of the method. What do you get now?

Comment: still getting underfined in the console

Comment: I see you have edited your initial post (better not to do this - keep the original so the answers make sense, and add an EDIT section instead). My previous comment still holds: your `addGame` method does not return anything, so your logging function logs `undefined`)

Comment: Also, change your callback to `function(error, title){ console.log(title) }`, otherwise you are reading the `error` field instead of the `result` field, which is `undefined` if there are no errors

Comment: Okay, I think that works. Using the console, how can I read the user record to see if it saved?

Comment: Not sure you can. Do the following: `function(error, user){ console.log(user.games) }` - assuming your `addGame` method returns the user record to the client